# How to use session on masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have added a login and logout button on my masterpage , i want to hide both of them from login and registration page and keep login button visible before login and logout button after login on other pages .How can i do that.

Comment: assign user name or id to a session variable,  `session["user"]` then check for null or empty in page load and handle visibility

Comment: Can you please tell me more about visibility  and where to write in login.aspx.cs or masterpage.master.cs

Answer (score 0):

Set Login button visibility to true and Logout button visibility to false, by default, in your aspx page. After successful login (on login button click), assign user name to Session and set Login button visibility to false, Logout button visibility to true like below.

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["UserName"] = UserName; //Assign user name
   Login.Visible =true;
   Logout.Visible =true;
}
```

In your master page, page load should have condition to check session is null or not. This is because if your session is lost, you have to let user to login again.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserName"] != null)
    {
      Logout.Visible =true;
      Login.Visible =false;
    }
    else
    {
      Login.Visible =true;
      Logout.Visible =false;
    }
}
```